# Wrong pdf output size

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, diagrams, resolution, pixelated

I'm trying to create an image (.pdf) that should be filled with black and white thick lines.

The code I'm using is working pretty good except for the fact that the matrix output size is not correct and this is generating a problem with the resolution of the image.

This is my code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=jpg]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \foreach \x in {0.4,0.8,1.2,...,200}{
    \draw [line width=0.2 mm] (\x mm ,20.2) -- (\x mm ,0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I was expecting to have 1000 line with a total width of 20 cm but the image real width is 19,4 (I don't know if it's actually plotting 1000 lines). This i think is generating an error with the resolution of the image because the output is this

[image]

If you zoom in you will see black and white lines with an equal width.

P.S. my pixel size is 0,18mm so I should be able to draw a 0,2mm line without problems

Comment: Errr, 200/0.4 does not equal 1000!

Comment: Isn't this saying 200/0,2 ?

Comment: `0.4,0.8,1.2,...2` would give you 5 values; what you have above yields a list with 500 values in it.

Comment: The fact is I'm trying to fill the screen with 0,18mm width (I know the value is set at 0,2mm atm) black and white lines. I was testing the code to see if I was doing it right but from what you're telling me it seems like I'm making some mistakes. right ?

Comment: Note that the lines will be centred on the points you've specified so the line at `0.4mm` will be a rectangle with the left side at `0.3mm` and the right at `0.5mm`. Also, `(0,0)` is not in your image, so the left hand boundary will be at `0.3mm` where the first line is drawn. You are getting, I think, 999 lines the values of `x` yield 500 lines in black. There are 499 gaps in between which are the white lines, for a total of 999.

Comment: When I compile to PDF, I get an image which is 200 x 202 mm.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the explanation! That might come in handy in the future but I think at the moment that doesn't affect much the issues I'm having. If I understood well what you are saying is that on my total width i should add a0,6mm (0,3mm from the left side of the first column and 0,3 from the right side of the last column) right ?

Comment: I get 7.87 x 7.96 in which is 19.9898 x 20.2184 cm but if I measure it with a ruler that is not what I get

Comment: Change units in your viewer to cm/mm, in that way you can be sure from the viewers perspective. Also, when doing implicit for loops on reals you come into some numerical problems of accuracy. First correcting your loop: `{0.1,0.5,.9,...,199.9}`, then you will find that the last column is placed here `19.69696mm` whereas it _should_ be `19.7mm` exactly. Note that the last line will not be present! This is because `TikZ` does numerics in `LaTeX` and the accuracy is not that great, you should probably use the fpu library instead.

Comment: @zeroth thank you ! I can accept up to a 1,5%-2% error so 19.98 is definitely not a problem. The fact is that I'm still having issues with the resolution. I don't understand why this is occurring because the thickness of the line is slightly bigger then my pixel. Some lines look way thicker then other but if i zoom in they are all with the same width

Comment: Well your screen has pixels as well! :) If it looks correct when you zoom, then definitely it is correct.

Comment: Yeah but the fact is that this type of images will be used in full screen in a video to generate like an optical illusion hence what I need to have is an image that at 100% size has the lines equals :)

Comment: If, when you zoom, you see the correct thing, then your problem will not lie in the viewer, it will lie in the hardware that represents the data. However, certain viewers allows to have their own precision for viewing compression, in Adobe Reader you can try and increase the precision in the `Page Display` preference tab.

Comment: And to populate the whole screen I should manually calculate the size and define the loop or is there any function ?

Comment: @user2425899 if the specified line width is "slightly bigger than my pixel" wouldn't you expect some to be twice as wide as others, depending where the line centre is relative to the pixel boundaries they will 1 or 2 pixels wide when rendered.

Comment: And this is all I was trying to figure out. How can I draw the line to be 1px and fit exactly in my screen px so that this error doesn't occur